# Problems suspending and resuming a thread

Tags: java, multithreading, exception

I am new to java programming and trying threading for the first time. I have created a thread to print the even numbers, and then a thread to print odd numbers. In the odd number thread there is a suspend() method after the number 11 to be printed. And after that there is another block to print odd numbers from 13 to 21. In main() I joined the 2 threads. In main function first I called thread t1(even number) and then joined it with thread t2(odd number). As there is suspend it will suspend the output after printing 11 it pauses there. But after that when i call t2.resume() that doesn't continue printing 13 to 21. Why it isn't printing the rest? and how can I make it resume?

Here's the code, please take a look:

```
class Hi extends Thread {
    
    public void run(){
        try{
            for(int i=0; i<=10; i++){
                System.out.println("1st: " + (2*i));
                sleep(100);
            }
        } catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

```
class Hello extends Thread {
    
    public void run(){
        try {
            for(int i=0; i<=5; i++){
                System.out.println("2nd: " +(2*i+1));
            }
            suspend();
            System.out.println(" Resumes again");
            for(int i=6; i<=10; i++){
                System.out.println("2nd: " +(2*i+1));
            }
        } catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }     
    }
}
```

```
public class thread {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Hi t1 = new Hi();
        Hello t2 = new Hello();
        t1.start();
        try {
            t1.join();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        t2.start();
        t2.resume();
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
1st: 0
1st: 2
1st: 4
1st: 6
1st: 8
1st: 10
1st: 12
1st: 14
1st: 16
1st: 18
1st: 20
Exception in thread "main" 2nd: 1
java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException
2nd: 3
2nd: 5
2nd: 7
2nd: 9
2nd: 11
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:791)
    at thread.main(thread.java:57)
```

After this the program isn't exiting, I have to exit the program manually (ctrl+c) in the terminal.

Comment: Why post poorly formatted code? It's hard enough to understand someone else's code, why make it harder than it has to be?

Comment: Also, `suspend()` is deprecated -- so you should not be calling this method (or extending Thread, for that matter).

Comment: Same goes for that wall of text in the beginning. You want other humans to spend their time to help you, so please make that as easy as possible: by writing up content that is EASY to digest.

Comment: And then: empty catch blocks is a really bad practice. Never do that, at least PRINT the exception. otherwise, you are just suppressing errors.

Comment: I have put in the effort to format your code. In the future, please put in this effort yourself. Again, no sense in making your code and question harder to understand than it has to be, no?

Comment: **Do not** call [suspend](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#suspend()) or [resume](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#resume()) under any circumstances.  They don’t work properly.  Read the links to understand why.  In general, it is essential for Java programmers to get in the habit of reading the documentation of the methods they use.  Cooperation between threads is normally done with synchronization or with the classes in java.util.concurrent.

Comment: I have to wonder whether you understood the exercise. Usually, when anybody asks here about threads printing odd and even numbers, they want the numbers printed in ascending order, but they want the two threads to _take turns_ printing them. (i.e., the "odd" thread prints "1", then the "even" thread prints "2", then the "odd" thread prints "3", and so on.)

Answer (score 0):

> After this the program isn't exiting, I have to exit the program manually (ctrl+c) in the terminal.

Aside from the fact that you should not be using `suspend()` and `resume()`, I believe your problem is a classic race condition.  The main thread is calling `t2.start()` and then `t2.resume()` but the thread is not suspended yet.  The main thread throws an exception and then the `t2` thread finishes its printing and calls `suspend()`.  There is no one left to resume it so the thread never finishes and you have to control-c your program.

You should make a couple of change to your example code.  First off use wait/notify instead of `suspend()`.  For example, have the `Hello` thread do:

```
// t2 thread shouldn't use suspend which is deprecated for good reason
synchronized (this) {
    wait();
}
```

Then in the main thread you need to loop until the thread is in a wait state before notify-ing it.   Something like:

```
while (true) {
    if (t2.getState() == State.WAITING) {
        synchronized (t2) {
            t2.notify();
        }
        break;
    }
    Thread.sleep(100);
}
```

These sorts of thread exercises where one thread is locked stepped with another (aside from a `join()` at the end) are a bad example of threading IMO.

Couple other comments.  You should `join()` with the `Hello` thread at the end of your code, never catch `Exception` if you can help it since it hides exceptions that may be the source of problems (at least print them as @GhostCat recommended), and also always re-interrupt your threads when you catch `InterruptedException`:

```
try {
    t2.join();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // always a good pattern
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> when i call `t2.resume()` that doesn't continue printing 13 to 21. Why it isn't printing the rest?

[@Gray answered that one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69994060/801894). TLDR: Your main thread calls `t2.resume()` *before* your `t2` thread calls `suspend()`.

I am curious to know what Java version you are using. I'm running JDK11 on macOS, and I can't get your program to throw that `java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException`, but I'm *guessing* that in whatever JDK and OS you are using, the exception is thrown when your main thread tries to `resume()` a thread that isn't suspended.

---

> how can I make it resume?

I would use a [`Semaphore`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html).

Let the `t2` thread wait to `acquire()` a "permit" from a semaphore, and let the main thread `release()` a permit *to* the semaphore at the appropriate time.

I changed your program by replacing the `suspend()` call with `sem.acquire()`, and by replacing the `resume()` call with `sem.release()`. I also threw a call to `Thread.sleep()` into the main thread before it releases the semaphore so that you can see the pause.  Here's the whole thing:

```java
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

class Hi extends Thread {   // This class is exactly the same as yours.
    public void run(){
        try{
            for(int i=0; i<=10; i++){
                System.out.println("1st: " + (2*i));
                sleep(100);
            }
        } catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
class Hello extends Thread {

    private Semaphore sem;          // new member variable

    public Hello(Semaphore sem) {   // new constructor to set the new member.
        this.sem = sem;
    }
    
    public void run(){
        try {
            for(int i=0; i<=5; i++){
                System.out.println("2nd: " +(2*i+1));
            }

            // Wait to "acquire" a permit from the semaphore. This won't
            //  return until the main thread "releases" a permit _to_ the
            //  semaphore.
            sem.acquire();

            System.out.println(" Resumes again");
            for(int i=6; i<=10; i++){
                System.out.println("2nd: " +(2*i+1));
            }
        } catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }     
    }
}

public class Wonk {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        // Create a semaphore that initially has 0 "permits."
        Semaphore s = new Semaphore(0);

        Hi t1 = new Hi();
        Hello t2 = new Hello(s);
        t1.start();
        try {
            t1.join();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        t2.start();
        waitabit(5000);  // Sleep 5 seconds, and then...
        s.release();     // ...Release the Hounds!!
    }

    private static void waitabit(int numMilliseconds) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(numMilliseconds);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```